# Python parsing API response Json body nested data

Tags: python, json

I am trying to call get api using python and fetch the covid vaccine details and storing into one proper formate. Into the same I am able to fetch CENTER data like "center_id,name, address,state_name" but I am not able to fetch the SESSIONS data as below

[image]

Below is how I am parsing the JSON response.

```
dataJ = json.loads(r.text)
for i in range(len(dataJ['centers'])):
    center = dataJ['centers'][i]['name']
    address = dataJ['centers'][i]['address']
    state = dataJ['centers'][i]['state_name']
    district = dataJ['centers'][i]['district_name']
    pin = dataJ['centers'][i]['pincode']
    date =dataJ['centers'][i]['date']
    print(center,"-",address,"-",state,"-",district,"-",pin,"-",date)
```

It gives me error as below

date =dataJ['centers'][i]['date']
KeyError: 'date'

Can someone please help me in this regard ?

Comment: Could you please share what you have tried?

Comment: What problem are you having? You access it just like any of the other data you mentioned. The value will be a list of dictionaries.

Comment: dataJ = json.loads(r.text)
for i in range(len(dataJ['centers'])):
    center = dataJ['centers'][i]['name']
    address = dataJ['centers'][i]['address']
    state = dataJ['centers'][i]['state_name']
    district = dataJ['centers'][i]['district_name']
    pin = dataJ['centers'][i]['pincode']
    date =dataJ['centers'][i]['date']
    print(center,"-",address,"-",state,"-",district,"-",pin,"-",date)  I am using for loop to parse the data but throw error like " date =dataJ['centers'][i]['date']
KeyError: 'date'"

Comment: Don't put code in a comment, edit the original question and add it there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do something similar to the `sessions` array, just like you did with the `centers` array.  See the `NEW` marked section below:

```
dataJ = json.loads(r.text)
for i in range(len(dataJ['centers'])):
    center = dataJ['centers'][i]['name']
    address = dataJ['centers'][i]['address']
    state = dataJ['centers'][i]['state_name']
    district = dataJ['centers'][i]['district_name']
    pin = dataJ['centers'][i]['pincode']
    date =dataJ['centers'][i]['date']
    print(center,"-",address,"-",state,"-",district,"-",pin,"-",date)

    # NEW: now process each session like you want
    for j in range(len(dataJ['centers'][i]['sessions'])):
        # do what you want with the session here:
        # it's also easier to use variables rather than reproducing the entire index sequence repeatedly
        session = dataJ['centers'][i]['sessions'][j]
        session_id = session['session_id']
        # ...
```

Comment: Thanks, Wes Hardaker for your prompt help. It's working fine. You rock!